# Prestashop - How to modify a module with an external module tpl

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I'm working on Prestashop. I would like to know if we can modify a prestashop template with a personnal module without change the original files of Prestashop ?

For example, I would like :

`Form title`

`OriginalLabel__1 : [Textfiel]`

`OriginalLabel_2 : [Textfiel]`

`OriginalLabel_3 : [Textfiel]`

`PersonnalLabel_1 : [Textfiel]`

`OriginalLabel_4 : [Textfiel]`

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can override original core code of Prestashop using override mechanism of Prestashop. You can override classes and controllers of Prestashop define new function overridden file in your module.
You can override these files in `{your_module}/override/claases}` or `{your_module}/override/controllers/{front| admin}` more documentation is here from native [documentation of Prestashop](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors)
Even you can override PHP files of others module in `{your_module}/override/modules/{the_rest_of_path_to_module_file}`

But if you you want to modify template files of Prestashop theme using module then forge it, first of all understand the point, view files are meant to modify in each and every CMS or framework. You should not be such sticky with template files.

One possible thing is you can use jQquery/Javascript to add html content run time anywhere in your Prestashop website but it will be not good for structure of Prestashop and it will never be considered while cowling your site by search engines.

As [an experienced Prestashop developer](http://www.vipulhadiya.com/) i assure you there is no danger to change any template files of Prestashop theme, just modify it as per your need.